# What's the critical temperature of the XY model on a triangular lattice

Tags: statistical-mechanics, critical-phenomena

I've been looking deeply into many bibliographic references without finding the answer. I would be interested in knowing the numerical value of the critical 2d XY spin model on triangular lattice. Being derived analytically (if possible) or from Monte-Carlo doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the relevant paper that would answer your question:
http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.57.8472

Comment: Yes, indeed they do locate the critical temperature using the 4th Binder cumulant, though my simulations are giving me different results on the x and y axis, I definitely need to look deeper into that. Many thanks ;)